# Rendering a component onClick

Tags: typescript, react-redux

Possible duplicate. I've tried the solutions from several other posts but my solution still does not work. I am trying to render a component from onClick.
The function getModal() gets called and displays the console.logs but the component does not get rendered. Any solution or advise would appreciated.

All the codes are snippets

This is my TestGroup.tsx

```
export class ListGroup extends React.Component<IProps> {
  getModal = () => {
    return (
      console.log("hello"),
      console.log("world"),
      (
        <TestGroup
          tesyState={this.props.testState}
          onUpdateSelectedTest={this.props.onUpdateSelectedTest}
        />
      )
    );
  };

  public render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <ul
          className="list-group"
          style={{
            marginTop: "20px",
            display: "inline-block"
          }}
        >
          {filterTest.map(filterTest => (
            <li
              className="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
              onClick={() => {
                this.props.onUpdateSelectedTest(filterTest);
                this.getModal();
              }}
            >
              {filterTest.testPN}: {filterTest.description}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my QuestionGroup.tsx: 
I will be rendering a modal but as test I just want to see the "Hello World"

```
export class QestionGroup extends React.Component<IProps> {

  public render() {
    //const onAfterOpenFn = () => {};
    //const onAfterCloseFn = () => {};

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onClick` method does not render returned components.

You have to add a `state` variable to show/hide the modal:

```
interface IState {
  showModal: boolean;
}

export class ListGroup extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  // Define a state variable to show/hide the modal
  public state: IState = {
    showModal: false
  };

  showModal = () => {
    // Show the modal
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  };

  public render() {
    const { showModal } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <ul
          className="list-group"
          style={{
            marginTop: "20px",
            display: "inline-block"
          }}
        >
          {filterTest.map(filterTest => (
            <li
              className="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
              onClick={() => {
                this.props.onUpdateSelectedTest(filterTest);
                this.showModal(); // <-- Function has been renamed
              }}
            >
              {filterTest.testPN}: {filterTest.description}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        // Show the modal if showModal is true
        {showModal && (
          <TestGroup
            tesyState={this.props.testState}
            onUpdateSelectedTest={this.props.onUpdateSelectedTest}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you. So should I create the functions to hide modal inside my TestGroup.tsx or the QuestionGroup.tsx? Or should state be included in the redux store?

Comment: What I usually do is pass a `close` function to the modal so that it can close itself with a cross button. This way the state of the modal is handled by its parent which gives you more flexibility (for example you can have the modal shown by default on a page but closed on another). About storing the state in the parent or in the redux store it depends on the use case. Usually it's stored on the parent because it's straightforward. But I had a case where I had to trigger the render of a modal from a service depending on the response of the API. Here the redux store made sense.